# Jquery Click Not working After making Panel Visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a Image in panel after textbox. On the page load, the panel in invisible.

After selecting value in drop down list, panel will become visible.

Jquery image click is not working after panel becomes visible.

I am using UpdatePanel for Drop down list postback, Will it be the reason ?

If not, how to fix this ?

```
 <tr>
      <td colspan="2" class="invisible">
         <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
             <ContentTemplate>
                 <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlMonitor" Width="100%" Visible="false" CssClass="panelstyle" >
                   <table style="width: 100%">
                      <tr>
                         <td>Periodic Review Admin:<span style="color: red">*</span>
                          </td>
                          <td>
                          <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtPeriodicReviewAdmin" CssClass="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" MaxLength="50"></asp:TextBox>
                      <img src="../Images/Binoculars.png" id="imgPRAdmin" />
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </asp:Panel>
                 </ContentTemplate>
               <Triggers>
                 <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlMonitor" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                </Triggers>
           </asp:UpdatePanel>
       </td>
    </tr>


 $("#imgPRAdmin").click(function (e) {              
      $("#divSearch").dialog({
          open: function () {
              $(this).closest(".ui-dialog")
              .find(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close")
              .removeClass("ui-dialog-titlebar-close");
          },
          title: "Search Employee",
          show: "fade",
          modal: true,
          width: '55%',
          height: 500
      });
  });
```

Comment: How do you subscribe to image click? Via click or via Live? for UpdatePanel you should use Live method

Comment: we really need some code to see what is going on?

Comment: @webdad3 I added code. Let me know, if you need more

Answer (score 0):

`UpdatePanel` will replace DOM elements, so `click()` will subscribe just on the original DOM element. When UpdatePanel refreshes own content with new items, it will replace DOM elements, and they won't have click subscription.

You need to use [`on`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) function. In previous version of jQuery it was `live`, but then it was deprecated

```
 $("body").on('click', "#imgPRAdmin", function (e) {              
      $("#divSearch").dialog({
          open: function () {
              $(this).closest(".ui-dialog")
              .find(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close")
              .removeClass("ui-dialog-titlebar-close");
          },
          title: "Search Employee",
          show: "fade",
          modal: true,
          width: '55%',
          height: 500
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use delegation. Change this -

```
$("#imgPRAdmin").click(function (e) {
```

to this -

```
$("body").on('click', '#imgPRAdmin', function (e) {
```

This accounts for the event bubbling up the DOM tree.